# How to convert a Gatling jsonFeeder with nested structures to json request body?

Tags: json, scala, gatling, scala-gatling

I have a json feeder reading from a file a json array like this:

```
[{ "a": {"b": 1} }, { "a": {"b": 2} }]
```

When I use it for a request body it's sent like `ArraySeq(HashMap(..` instead of the actual json. How can I convert the Parsed Json back to Json keeping the feeder approach?

```
val jsonFileFeeder = jsonFile("requests.json").circular

val scn = scenario("cost estimation")
  .feed(jsonFileFeeder)
  .exec(
    http("request_1")
      .post("/")
      .body(StringBody(
        """{
    "a":  "${a}"
}"""
      )).asJson
  )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `jsonStringify()`, see [documentation](https://gatling.io/docs/gatling/reference/current/session/expression_el/).

```scala
val jsonFileFeeder = jsonFile("requests.json").circular

val scn = scenario("cost estimation")
  .feed(jsonFileFeeder)
  .exec(
    http("request_1")
      .post("/")
      .body(StringBody(
        """{
    "a":  "${a.jsonStringify()}"
}"""
      )).asJson
  )
```